# Letters only Alexa Skill intent slot

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

### The problem

I have an intent with slot type `AMAZON.MusicRecording`.

When I say `first` in that slot, I get the text `1st` in the request.

### What I have tried

Find and replace of `1st` to `first` on the request text.

The method above will not easily handle `31th` and etc. Plus, it will not prevent Alexa from changing `one plus five` into `1 + 5`.

## My question

Is there a way to ask Alexa to provide a letters-only slot?

Or is there an easy way to make text into letters only in Python?